# Initialize log4net settings from database

Tags: c#, sql, initialization, log4net

Currently my application (C# Console App) uses file to initialize log4net, is there a way to initialize the log4net configurations from the database ?

I can either save my current file as XML in DB (SQL) but I am not sure how to initialize log4net from that within my application.

EDIT :

Current Implementation:

```
 _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            var file = new FileInfo(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4net.Config"]);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(file);
```

AppSettings has a location of the physical file which has the following:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\%property{LogName}" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <datePattern value="MM-dd-yyyy'.log'" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level – %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>

    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Well what code do you use to create your log4net instance at the moment?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @Arran - Please see updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [overload to XmlConfigurator.Configure that takes a stream as the parameter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_7.html) - so you just read your config from the database, turn it into a stream, and pass it to that method:

```
string config = GetConfigFromDb();
using (var MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config))
{ 
     log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ms);
}
```