# Read settings from database in log4net

Tags: log4net

Does log4net has **standard feature** to read settings from database?
I mean, on my application I store only connection string, and all other settings log4net get from database.

In [Initialize log4net settings from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236965/initialize-log4net-settings-from-database) display how to load settings from DB, but loading becomes manually by external code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize log4net settings from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236965/initialize-log4net-settings-from-database)